# querying a directory for files that are complete (not copy-in-progress)

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to use `FileInfo.CreationTime`, but it doesn't represent the copy finish time.

I am trying to get a list of files in a directory. The problem is that the call also returns files which are not yet finished copying.

If I try to use the file, it returns an error stating that the file is in use.

How can you query for files that are fully copied?

As below code. `Directory.GetFiles()` returns which are not yet finished copying.

my test file size is over 200Mb.

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(strDirectoryPath)){

                txtResultPrint.AppendText("ERROR : Wrong Directory Name! ");
            }else{
                string[] newFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strDirectoryPath,"*.epk");

                _epkList.PushNewFileList(newFiles);

                if(_epkList.IsNewFileAdded()){
                    foreach (var fileName in _epkList.GetNewlyAddedFile()){
                        txtResultPrint.AppendText(DateTime.Now.Hour + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second + "   => ");
                        txtResultPrint.AppendText(fileName + Environment.NewLine);
                        this.Visible = true;
                        notifyIconMain.Visible = true;
                    }

                }else{

                }
            }
```

Comment: can you update your post to include the code you're using?

Comment: sorry now I am in my office.  when i finish day job, let me add codes

Comment: I don't believe that Windows has a concept of copy-in-progress.

Comment: Directory.GetFiles() returns which are not yet finished copying.

Comment: Doesn't that return all files, including those which have finished copying?

Comment: sometimes Directory.GetFiles() waits until the copy finishs, sometimes not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance and best-practices aren't huge concerns then you could simply wrap the failing file operation in an inner-scoped try/catch.

```
 using System.IO;
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("pathToFiles");
 foreach (string file in files) {
     FileStream fs = null;
     try {
         //try to open file for exclusive access
         fs = new FileStream(
             file, 
             FileMode.Open, 
             FileAccess.Read, //we might not have Read/Write privileges
             FileShare.None   //request exclusive (non-shared) access
         );
     } 
     catch (IOException ioe) {
         //File is in use by another process, or doesn't exist
     }
     finally {
         if (fs != null)
             fs.Close();
     }
 }
```

This isn't really the best design advice as you shouldn't be relying on exception handling for this sort of thing, but if you're in a pinch and it's not code for a client or for your boss then this should work alright until a better solution is suggested or found.

Comment: Try to open the file for exclusive access (i.e. `FileShare.None`). If that works, the file is not in the process of being copied.

Comment: Good advice @JimMischel. I've added you're suggestion to my answer to make it more explicit. Also, after doing some more reading I'm not sure that there way to do this without using exception handling.

Comment: @Jim Mischel I can solve the problem with your comment. the FileStream returns an exception while they are copy-in-progress

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to change thy copying itself?

If yes (and if you can guarantee that your program will always execute on NTFS on Windows Vista or newer), you can use [Transactional NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS) to wrap the copy in a single transaction. File(s) being copied will only become visible to the rest of the world **after** you commit the transaction, so you'll never even see the partially copied files.

Unfortunately Transactional NTFS is not accessible directly from .NET Framework - you'll need to P/Invoke into Win32 APi functions such as: `CreateTransaction`, `CommitTransaction`, `RollbackTransaction`, `CopyFileTransacted` (and other *Transacted functions).